# How to make character count with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to correctly make a character count with JS.
My code seems is incorrect, what i'm doign wrong?

```
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

    var str = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
    var res = str.innerHTML = str.value.length;
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: is your code in a separate JavaScript section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work for you

```js
var x = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML
var str = x.length;
alert("length is:" +str);
console.log(str);
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Muhammad but what about class, in my case i'm using class, it's not working the same for class

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) definition of the function it returns an array. So you either want the length of the array `str.length` or to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like collection of elements. Iterate over it and fetch the `value`:

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
[].forEach.call(str, function(el){
   var res = el.value.length;
   el.innerHTML = res;
   console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Not desirable? That is what OP Wants.

Comment: it give's me an error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get the length of the content of an element. For that you should be using id selector, not class selector, there can be many elements with the same class but not with the same id. So you should give it some id like: `<p id='some_id' class='text'>` 
Now you can get it through:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML.length
```

To avoid any leading or trailing spaces, and to get exact length of text, you can try this:

```
document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML.trim().length
```

Comment: but what about class, in my case i'm using class, it's not working the same for class

Comment: getElementByClass() returns an array of elements. You can refer to @void's answer. It works for class. It makes sense if you have more than one such element.